# Desserialização XML

Tags: c#, xml, desserialização

Tenho um método que faz um consulta a um WebService, com o retorno eu faço uma desserialização do XML recebido. Acontece que caso eu faça a desserialização em memoria ele da um erro dizendo:

> xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" não esperado

Porém se eu faço o mesmo procedimento salvando o arquivo em disco e usando o `StreamReader` ele funciona normalmente. Eu comentei no código qual parte está dando o erro e qual está funcionado.
*Tem POG dentro do `foreach`, por favor ignorar, a não ser que ela seja o problema.*

Qual o motivo deste erro?

XML:

```
<resNFe xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versao="1.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
    <chNFe>5616516516516516816165165156</chNFe>
    <CNPJ>12345678654231</CNPJ>
    <xNome>bla bla bla</xNome>
    <IE>651651654</IE>
    <dhEmi>2016-06-28T09:00:04-03:00</dhEmi>
    <tpNF>1</tpNF>
    <vNF>10049.69</vNF>
    <digVal>asdasdasdzc5asr41fa564s</digVal>
    <dhRecbto>2016-06-28T09:16:34-03:00</dhRecbto>
    <nProt>3531351313235151</nProt>
    <cSitNFe>1</cSitNFe>
</resNFe>
```

Código:

```
public void ConsultaDfe(string CNPJ)
{
    DistribuicaoDFe xmlDfe = new DistribuicaoDFe();

    xmlDfe.ModeloDocumento = "NFE";
    xmlDfe.Versao = "1.0";
    xmlDfe.CNPJEmissor = CNPJ;
    xmlDfe.TpAmb = "1";
    xmlDfe.UsarUltimoNSU = "N";
    ClienteWebService cliente = new ClienteWebService();
    XDocument Xml = cliente.Envio(SerializaObjeto.SerializeToString(xmlDfe), CNPJ);

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RetornoDFe));
    XmlReader reader = Xml.CreateReader();
    RetornoDFe retornoDFe = (RetornoDFe)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);

    foreach (var item in retornoDFe.Documentos)
    {
        XmlNode[] _docXml = (XmlNode[])item.DocXML;
        string base64 = _docXml[0].Value.ToString();
        byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(ms);

        XmlSerializer _xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(resNFe));

        XmlReader _reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);

        //Não funciona  - xmlns:"" não esperado

        var _resNFe = (resNFe)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(_reader);

    }

    // Funciona 100%
    var resnfe = new resNFe();
    string caminho = @"C:\home\13160604301024000131550010001971591190360567.xml";
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(resNFe));
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(caminho);
    resnfe = (resNFe)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenta passar a string ao invés do XmlReader e criar um stringReader por exemplo:

```
public static T LoadFromXMLString<T>(string xmlText)
{
    var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
}
```

e chamar

```
LoadFromXmlString<resNFe>(suaString);
```

Comment: Jovem, funcionou maravilhosamente. Perdi um dia com isso. Obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento. Já pesquisei e ainda não entendi o por que deste erro com o XmlReader.......