# Diferenças entre XmlReader, StreamReader e StringReader na desserialização

Tags: c#, .net, xml, desserialização

Fiz a seguinte pergunta aqui no stackoverflow [link pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147864/desserializa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-xml/147951#147951).

Durante a deserialização dependendo do stream que se usa pode ocorrer um erro no namespaces do XML, conforme o link da pergunta.

Exemplos do código que tem o erro do namespace.

```
byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(ms);

        XmlSerializer _xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(resNFe));

        XmlReader _reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);

        //Não funciona  - xmlns:"" não esperado

        var _resNFe = (resNFe)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(_reader);
```

Código que funciona:

```
     // Funciona 100%
    var resnfe = new resNFe();
    string caminho = @"C:\home\13160604301024000131550010001971591190360567.xml";
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(resNFe));
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(caminho);
    resnfe = (resNFe)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();
```

Este também funciona:

```
public static T LoadFromXMLString<T>(string xmlText)
{
var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
}
```

Lembrando que esta sendo usado o mesmo XML e a mesma classe serializada.

Alguem sabe dizer o porque deste erro de namespace dependendo do stream utilizado ?

XmlDocument:

```
<resNFe xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versao="1.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<chNFe>5616516516516516816165165156</chNFe>
<CNPJ>12345678654231</CNPJ>
<xNome>bla bla bla</xNome>
<IE>651651654</IE>
<dhEmi>2016-06-28T09:00:04-03:00</dhEmi>
<tpNF>1</tpNF>
<vNF>10049.69</vNF>
<digVal>asdasdasdzc5asr41fa564s</digVal>
<dhRecbto>2016-06-28T09:16:34-03:00</dhRecbto>
<nProt>3531351313235151</nProt>
<cSitNFe>1</cSitNFe>
</resNFe>
```

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de `_reader `?

Comment: É um XmlDocument

Comment: Qual conteúdo após `XmlReader _reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);`

Comment: Após esta parte já vai para var _resNFe = (resNFe)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(_reader); que é onde acontece a exceção.

Comment: Na verdade eu queria saber qual o conteúdo de `_reader ` após executar `XmlReader _reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);` Pode ser que o resultado não venha no formato esperado para deserialização.

Comment: Entedi, eu observei que o resultado aparentemente é o mesmo em todos os exemplos. Inclusive eu até fiz alguns testes com outros Xml`s e o stream sempre é o mesmo em todos os exemplos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser um bug na implementação do `XmlNodeReader` que eles não quiseram resolver. [Esta página aqui](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772329/xmlserializer-xsi-type-attributes-with-namespaces-dont-deserialize-correctly-with-xmlnodereader) (que, por sinal, leva a [essa resposta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692532/namespace-prefix-not-defined-when-it-actually-is-defined/4694510#4694510)) possui mais detalhes sobre o bug.

Na própria página, um dos contribuidores disse que foi decidido não consertar o bug. Então, o melhor mesmo é usar `StreamReader` ou `StringReader`.

EDIT: bom, acho que eu posso explicar melhor o que acontece. No `XmlNodeReader`, o código que vai comparar os namespaces é parecido com isso aqui:

```
(object) ((System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName)xsiType).Namespace == (object)id2_namespace))
```

Quer dizer que ele faz uma comparação de objetos (que é feita por referência), e não uma comparação de strings (que é feita por valor). Como um objeto só é igual a ele mesmo, essa comparação sempre dá problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, eu jamais imaginaria que esse erro seria um bug......